# Linux--Command shell color

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

Not long ago I put a line of code in my .bashrc script in order to reduce the space of the text before $. It worked but the color changed to green and I would like to bring it back to white without removing the function of the code.
Here's the code:

```
PS1='\[\e[1;32m\][\u@\h \W]\$\[\e[0m\] '
```

Comment: This is not on topic for Stack Overflow, and would be more so on superuser.com. But it's the `\[\e[1;32m\]` sequence making your terminal green. If you remove that segment, as well as the `\[\e[0m\]` which resets the color to default, you should end up with a white prompt.

Comment: please consider migrating this question to super user. but you already got the answer i guess ;)